# Is it possible to use an extension method that also has an out parameter?

Tags: c#, .net, extension-methods, visual-studio-2012

Example:

```
public static string BoolToYesOrNo(this bool text, out string outAsHtmlName)
{
    string[] choices = { "Yes", "No", "N/A" };
    switch (text)
    {
        case true: outAsHtmlName = choices[0]; return choices[0];
        case false: outAsHtmlName = choices[1]; return choices[1];
        default: outAsHtmlName = choices[2]; return choices[2];
    }
}
```

throws an exception that no overload ... takes 1 argument, altough i am using 2 arguments.

```
myBool.BoolToYesOrNo(out htmlClassName);
```

this is the exact exception: CS1501: No overload for method 'BoolToYesOrNo' takes 1 arguments.

Comment: Yes, its possible - the error is likely due to something else. Show us more of your calling code and the exact compiler error.

Comment: Leave alone out thing. Why have a switch case for bool value. Use Ternary operator for this. With switch case you have to provide a default case apart from true and false cases which is illogical.

Comment: because i want to use an extension method so i will write it in as a readable manner as possible.

Comment: Nikhil is right. The switch makes no sense, there's no default option for a boolean value...

Comment: you can write it as `if (text) { outAsHtmlName = choices[0]; return choices[0]; } else { outAsHtmlName = choices[1]; return choices[1]; };` bool will have true or false. if you want to return `"N/A"` use `bool?` If you use bool, you can never return `"N/A"`

Comment: it does not matter i have a select list that requires N/A option as well and i have a nullable bool. Please focus on my question.

Comment: But why do you want to have the function return the value as both out parameter and return value ?

Comment: because a webgrid column takes as a parameter a func<> that accepts a dynamic item, that dynamic item chages for every row, so i have to return something from that part exactly as i don`t have direct acces do its enumeration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer on a MS forum, was a vs 2012 bug, and after installing the july 2012 update, everything worked fine. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This works fine for me with your code:

```
static void Main()
{
    bool x = true;
    string html;
    string s = x.BoolToYesOrNo(out html);
}
```

Most likely, you are missing `using` directive to the namespace of the type that declares `BoolToYesOrNo`, so add:

```
using The.Correct.Namespace;
```

to the top of your code file, where:

```
namespace The.Correct.Namespace {
    public static class SomeType {
        public static string BoolToYesOrNo(this ...) {...}
    }
}
```

Comment: nope it sees the code perfectly and the compiler does not complain at all. I must mention that i am using visual studio 2012 RC. its just when loading the razor page it displays the error in the browser page

Comment: @Freeman does it work if you use `SomeType.BoolToYesOrNo(...)` directly ?

Comment: @Freeman: are you sure that your extension method is inside a static class ?

Comment: 100 % sure, if i remove the uot parameter it works excellent.

Comment: @digEmAll he would get a "Extension method must be defined in a non-generic static class" in that case

Comment: @Alex I'm wondering if this is a deployment issue, i.e. since this is razor, maybe the dll in the web app is the old one, without the method.

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code this way and it works without any exceptions, the only thing I would point out if you are `giving a parameter with out` then you don't need the method to do any `return of string`

```
    bool b = true;
    string htmlName;
    string boolToYesOrNo = b.BoolToYesOrNo(out htmlName);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did to test this out:

1. I created a new C# Console Application (framework 4.5) in Visual Studio 2012 RC
2. Changed `program.cs` to look like this

(omitting `using`s)

```
namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    public static class testClass
    {
        public static string BoolToYesOrNo(this bool text, out string outAsHtmlName)
        {
            string[] choices = { "Yes", "No", "N/A" };
            switch (text)
            {
                case true: outAsHtmlName = choices[0]; return choices[0];
                case false: outAsHtmlName = choices[1]; return choices[1];
                default: outAsHtmlName = choices[2]; return choices[2];
            }
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            bool b = true;
            string result = string.Empty;
            string retval = b.BoolToYesOrNo(out result);
            Console.WriteLine(retval + ", " + result); //output: "Yes, Yes";
        }
    }
}
```

1. I hit F5 to run the program. The code ran perfectly. So, your method is in fact correct, and there is something wrong ... well, somewhere else. Double check the *braces*, sometimes if you miss one you get odd errors.

Answer (score 0):

I simply paste your code and it works fine. I tried both .net 3.5 and 4.0 and no compile error is shown and the results are correct.

Why this is an overload method?